# Persistent Shopping Cart & session.gc_maxlifetime

Tags: magento-1.7, cart, session, persistent

I've received some conflicting information online about this, but when enabling Magento's native Persistent Shopping Cart is it necessary to also modify the php value for `session.gc_maxlifetime` to match the time in seconds?

For example, if you look at this third party module on GitHub:

[clockworkgeek/Magento-Remember-Me](https://github.com/clockworkgeek/Magento-Remember-Me)

You'll see it mentions:

> This extension works by extending the lifetime of cookies, in all
>   likelihood your server will also need to extend the lifetime of it's
>   sessions. To do this add the following to the site's .htaccess file:

```
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 2592000
```

Do I need to change the PHP value, or will it function regardless?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For persistent shopping cart you should not need to.  Works only when customer is logged in.

But for regular guest browsing and admin sessions you need to.

Comment: Thanks for the info. If I also wanted to extend the guest cart persistence, should I also increase the cookie lifetime to match this at System → Config → Web → Session Cookie Management?

Comment: Exactly, and match that or exceed that with the GC setting.  You can also lengthen your admin setting under admin>system>config>admin.  Please accept above answer if it resolves your query.  Thank you.