# Modifying session.gc_maxlifetime results in front & back-end login loop

Tags: magento-1.7, php-5.4, session, persistent

After reading that you should modify the `session.gc_maxlifetime` value to match[<sup>1</sup>](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/60101/persistent-shopping-cart-session-gc-maxlifetime) the settings in:

1. `System` → `Config` → `Web` → `Session Cookie Management` → `Cookie Lifetime`, and
2. `System` → `Config` → `Persistent Shopping Cart` → `Persistence Lifetime (seconds)`

I matched all the values to 31536000 seconds (365 days) and had our hosts change the GC value to match this. After the change was made, both front & backend login pages would simply redirect you to the login page after a successful login.

The only way I could resovle this was to revert the GC value back to it's original value (1440).

As soon as it was reverted, the problem was resolved.
I could find *nothing* in the error logs regarding this.

Any ideas?

Comment: you also needs to set the time out in website and store configuration scope.

Comment: Did you try from multiple browsers and clear all contents from var/sessions? Sounds like your browser was trying to use your old cookies.

Comment: @ladle3000 This one slipped my mind. I didn't clear var/sessions, would this be a requirement after making this change? And tell me, would this empty all guest carts?

Comment: @moose Don't know for sure on that one, but would be what I would try.

Comment: And yes I think they'd lose their carts.

Comment: Thanks. Discussing with Nexcess to see what the procedure will be. Will report back.

Comment: any update on this ?

Comment: In this instance we had to restart the PHP-FPM, clear redis & memcached.